# I have this error "Batch update failed with HTTP status code 401; 1 replication tasks deleted" in my console for my eureka service

Tags: spring, security, netflix-eureka

When I run the other service s they register and after I get this error in my console.

I rechecked my security in the eureka service and in the other services that authenticate before loggingin.
my security class of eureka

```
package com.ml.discoveryservice.springsecurityConfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                //User.withUsername("username").password("{noop}password").roles("USER","ADMIN").build()
                User.withUsername("username").password("{noop}password").roles().build()
        );
    }


    
}
```

and this is my properte of eureka

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
#MODIFIER LE SERVICE DE DECOUVERTE D'EUREKA 
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

spring.security.basic.enabled = true
spring.security.user.name=username
spring.security.user.password=password
```

this is my propertie of my GatWay

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://username:password@localhost:8761/eureka/
#Nous allons cr�er une propri�t� de type rsa
rsa.public-key=classpath:certificats/public.pem
rsa.private-key=classpath:certificats/private.pem
```